# Guidance needed for jQuery pagination

Tags: php, jquery

Hi i am using jQuery pagination and presently it's looks like

```
<Prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 Next>
```

instead of above i need similar like this

`<Prev 1 2 3 . . . 11 12 Next>`

`<Prev 3 4 5 . . . 11 12 Next>`

`<Prev 5 6 7 . . . 11 12 Next>`

finally

`<Prev 1 . . . . 10 11 12 Next>`

Here is my corresponding code to understand the situation

```
var PerPage = 15;
var NumberOfItems = 180; //from db
var NumberOfPages = Math.ceil(NumberOfItems / PerPage);

 // to create Prev link
 var NavigationHtml = '<li class="previous"><a href="javascript:previous_history_trades();"><span></span></a></li>';
   var CurrentLink = 0;

 // to create total page numbers link
    while (NumberOfPages > CurrentLink) {
           NavigationHtml += '<li class="history_trades_page_link" longdesc="' + CurrentLink + '"><a href="javascript:go_to_history_trades_page(' + CurrentLink + ')">' + (CurrentLink + 1) + '</a></li>';
            CurrentLink++;

      }
     //to create next link
     NavigationHtml += '<li class="next"><a href="javascript:next_history_trades();"><span></span></a></li>';
      $('#history_trades_page_navigation').html(NavigationHtml);
```

and html

```
<div class="pagination pagination-mini-r">
  <ul id='history_trades_page_navigation'>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can i do this?

Comment: There are numerous plugins you can use. WIll be a lot easier than creating all the event handling and display logic from scratch

Comment: [Short list of some pagination plugins](http://php-team.blogspot.com/2009/05/10-jquery-datagrid-plugins.html)

Comment: @MikeB those are all grid plugins...was think more like this  http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/. Thre are many use cases for pagination without needing a grid

Comment: @charlietfl-nice link i'll try this out. was asked by curiosity to know something deep in jQuery.

Comment: @LearneR  that came from a very simple google search `jquery pagination`